# java chat client server with 2 computers

Tags: java

here is code for client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SimpleChatClient {
    JTextArea incoming;
    JTextField outgoing;
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleChatClient client = new SimpleChatClient();
        client.go();
    }
    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ludicrously Simple Chat Client");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
        incoming.setLineWrap(true);
        incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        incoming.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
        qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        outgoing = new JTextField(20);
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
        mainPanel.add(qScroller);
        mainPanel.add(outgoing);
        mainPanel.add(sendButton);
        setUpNetworking();
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        readerThread.start();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void setUpNetworking() {
        try {
            sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("networking established");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // close setUpNetworking
    public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                writer.println(outgoing.getText());
                writer.flush();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            outgoing.setText("");
            outgoing.requestFocus();
        }
    } // close inner class
    public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read " + message);
                    incoming.append(message + "\n");
                } // close while
} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        } // close run
    } // close inner class
}
```

here is code for server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class VerySimpleChatServer {
    ArrayList clientOutputStreams;
    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket sock;
        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            try {
                sock = clientSocket;
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        } // close constructor
        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read " + message);
                    tellEveryone(message);
                } // close while
} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        } // close run
    } // close inner class
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
    }
    public void go() {
        clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                t.start();
                System.out.println("got a connection");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // close go
    public void tellEveryone(String message) {
        Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
                writer.println(message);
                writer.flush();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // end while
    } // close tellEveryone
} // close class
```

when i run server on one computer and i run client on another computer with the ip adress of the server computer instead of 127.0.0.1, i get connection reset exception, any help on this?

here is the exception i get

```
networking established
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unkno
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unkno
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Un
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unk
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknow
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown S
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unkno
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unkno
        at SimpleChatClient$IncomingReader.run(S
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i should add that it works if i run both server and client on my own computer and enter my own ip adress instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the full stack trace?

Comment: same answer as before, check your firewall.